# Unity how to change LineRenderer sort point?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am working on a little 2d Top-view game project with Unity 2022.2.20
my player is a hacker who needs to hack stuff.
I am representing the hack being done with a `GameObject` (named Hackray) that has a `LineRenderer` component.

I've set up a Y-Axis sorting and I am rendering all the sprites in the environment.
I changed all the `SpriteRenderer` Sort point to Pivot and sprites pivots to BottomCenter to make my game render well.

However, since the Hackray is drawn through a `LineRenderer`, its sorting is by default based on its Center, and I don't know how to change that.

It causes a visual bug like this :

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

As you can see, when the center of the HackinRay has a Y value greater than the Computer bottom, the Computer is rendered after the HackinRay.

I would then like to change the `LineRenderer` Sort Point to a Custom Point (the center of the player's sprite would be perfect), but I don't know how I can do this.

I've searched a lot on internet about this but it seems very complicated to change Sort Point in unity, even with `SpriteRenderer` I can not change it to a Custom Point.

Is there a way to fix this ? Should I rather create a new custom script and render the line with a `SpriteRenderer` ?

And also I don't really understand the differences between those "Texture Modes" :

[image: Texture Modes]

The doc of unity explains it maybe well but I don't understand what differences bring `DistributePerSegment` and
`RepeatPerSegment`.

Comment: the texture modes only modify lets call it coloring of the line ... if you don't use any this setting doesn't matter at all. But in short: Stretch => stretch the texture over the entire line, Tile => repeats the texture based on texture scale, DistributePerSegment => repeats the texture assuming all vertices have equal distances, RepeatPerSegment => repeats the texture but for each segment (= line between two vertices) individually ... But anyway again: none of these have any influence on sorting

Comment: Before trying to solve it with a sprite renderer (basically why not .. simply rotate and scale it accordingly) you should first check with a manual one if this solves the issue at all ;)

Comment: Alright thanks a lot for the texture mode explaining ! Yeah it is what i thought, only affects the texture (fair enough).
And yes converting it to a custom SpriteRenderer is not a big deal, however I don't really understand what you mean "try with a manual one" ?
Thanks again for helping !

Comment: I just meant before you take the effort changing your implementation to a SpriteRenderer and apply the required rotation and position ... first make this setup manually in the scene directly and check if this actually resolves the issue .. otherwise you might put a lot work into implementing something that in the end still has the same issue ;)

Comment: ohh yeah I see well I will try this ! I'm pretty sure I can make it work this way !

Comment: alright it solves the issue ! let's create my own line with SpriteRenderer :D thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright seems like it is easier to achieve with a custom script using SpriteRenderer.

If you face the same problem, do not forget to change the pivot to BottomCenter in the Sprite Editor and then select Pivot for Sprite sort point and you should be fine.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).